# vuejs template including inside html

Tags: templates, vue.js, components

I'm having a custom component and I want it to print the given html.

```
<customComponent>
  <p>I want this to be shown at bottom of the created template</p>
</customComponent>
```

It seems simple but I cannot find any info/example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<slot>`

In customComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

Then:

```
<customComponent>
  <p>I want this to be shown at bottom of the created template</p>
</customComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CustomComponent.vue':

```
props: {
  text: String
}
```

and it's template:

```
<template>
  <p>{{text}}</p>
</template>
```

you include it like this:

`<custom-component text="I want this to be shown at bottom of the created template"></custom-component>`

Comment: I'm not needing a prop as it is lot of html I want to show in real app.Thx.